# Displaying results from multiple tables SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a database with 12 tables. I am doing a php query to pull the information from the database but I am not getting anything displayed. The query alone bridges all the tables starting with table `schedule` that have a foreign key related. Should I need to start the query from the table `class` and bridge with other tables?

[TABLE DESIGN- PICTURE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/class_des/table_structure.php)

If you like to duplicate my design- [QUERY](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/class_des/query_create.php)

```
$query = ("SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description
                FROM schedule 
                INNER JOIN section 
                ON class.id = section.class_id
                INNER JOIN faculty
                ON faculty.id = section.faculty_id
                INNER JOIN faculty
                ON faculty.id = office_hours.faculty_id
                INNER JOIN faculty_titles
                ON faculty_titles.faculty_id = faculty.id
                INNER JOIN faculty_education
                ON faculty_education.faculty_id = faculty.id 
                INNER JOIN section
                ON section.faculty_id = faculty.id 
                INNER JOIN class
                ON class.id = section.class_id
                INNER JOIN major_class_br
                ON major_class_br.class_id = class.id
                INNER JOIN  major_minor 
                ON major_class_br.major_minor_id = major_minor.id                
                 ");
      //execute query
      $result = mysql_query($query);

     if ($result){

    $totalhours = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
    {  
        print "<b>" . $row['class_name'] . "</b><br>";
        print $row['class_caption'] . "<br>";
        print $row['class_description'] . "<br>";
        print $row ['class_credit_hours'] . "hrs. <br>";
        print "------------------------------<br />";
        $totalhours += $row['class_credit_hours']; 
    }   
    }
```

[SQL fiddle query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28c29/2)

Comment: Maybe one of those rows doesn't exist? Check whether the foreign keys are nullable and if you should really be using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @charliecodex23 i found lot of table missing in the query file. please correct it in the SQL fiddler link, click `build schema` there and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description
             FROM schedule 
            INNER JOIN section 
            ON class.id = section.class_id
```

Right here there's a problem: you are doing a INNER JOIN using the field 'class.id' but the table 'class' isn't in either side of the JOIN. So it won't work.

The query should start like this:

```
SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description
             FROM class
            INNER JOIN section 
            ON class.id = section.class_id
```

And then do the JOIN with the table 'schedule' with the table it shares a common index (I guess it would be class).

The complete query should be something like this:

```
SELECT  class.class_name, class.class_caption, class.class_credit_hours, class.class_description
            FROM class
            INNER JOIN section 
            ON class.id = section.class_id
            INNER JOIN faculty 
            ON faculty.id = section.faculty_id OR faculty.id = office_hours.faculty_id
            INNER JOIN faculty_titles
            ON faculty_titles.faculty_id = faculty.id
            INNER JOIN faculty_education
            ON faculty_education.faculty_id = faculty.id 
            INNER JOIN major_class_br
            ON major_class_br.class_id = class.id
            INNER JOIN major_minor 
            ON major_class_br.major_minor_id = major_minor.id
            INNER JOIN sched_sect_br 
            ON sched_sect_br.section_id =  section.id
            INNER JOIN schedule
            ON schedule.id = sched_sect_br.schedule_id
            INNER JOIN semester
            ON semester.id = schedule.semester_id
            INNER JOIN office_hours
            ON schedule.id = office_hours.schedule_id AND faculty.id = office_hours.faculty_id
```

This query gets info from all the tables you have in your graph, aside from the event table, that isn't related to any other. But still this query should have more fields on the SELECT (you are only selection fields from the class table, I understand you'd want data from the other 10 tables as well), to do this simple add 'tablename.field' to the list of fields from the SELECT.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Can you show me the full correct query? I will be sure to accept your answer.

Comment: sure gimme a sec and i'll get it. By the way, I supose the fields you have in the SELECT are only temporary and you actually want to retrieve information from the tables you add with JOINs. I mean, it's weird to see a query that only retrieves info from the class table, and has so many JOINs but not a single WHERE clause involving the other tables.

Comment: +1 you are totally correct the fields i have in the `SELECT` are only temporary and will retrieve other things. thank you!